# How do I scroll to end of page using the requests-html library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I need to scrape the data but the entire data only generated when I scroll.

if I scrape before I scroll only some of the data is scraped not all.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

link="https://www.daraz.com.np/catalog/?q={}"
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
async def get_daraz():
    r = await asession.get(link.format("mouse"))
    await r.html.arender()
    return r.html
results = asession.run(get_daraz)


items_div=results[0].xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')

for item in items_div:
    print(item.xpath('//div/div/div[1]/div/a/img',first=True))
```

the above gives images of only first three.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) library to scroll the web page. Selenium works too, but is blocked by many websites.

```
pyautogui.moveTo(200,200) # move mouse to a blank spot on the screen. (x, y) coordinates.
pyautogui.click(200,200) # click spot on screen at the coordinates of your choice.
pyautogui.scroll(100) # you could use a higher number to scroll more to load the whole page.
```

Comment: but this needs the chrome to be open , im webscraping with no browserwindow .how do i use this technique on an html? i have no idea.